# How to download a file in FilleZilla using an URL with credentials?

Tags: ftp, url

How can I open FTP site and download a file in FileZilla with given link as follows

```
ftp://ftp-pub:avilex@ftp.avilex.ru/Pub/schooldesk/schooldesk-20171025.iso
```

supposed credentials are `ftp-pub` and `avilex` I got invalid credentials response from FTP server

the question is not FileZilla specific. I would use any FTP client with right credentials extracted from the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are not the credentials. FileZilla can accept credentials from an URL, if you paste the URL to the *"Host"* box on FileZilla toolbar.

The problem is that FileZilla cannot accept a file name in the URL. Only an initial path.

So if you paste the following URL:

```
ftp://ftp-pub:avilex@ftp.avilex.ru/Pub/schooldesk/
```

FileZilla will connect to that server and navigate to the `/Pub/schooldesk/`.

But you will have to locate the file (`schooldesk-20171025.iso`) and initiate the download manually.

---

You will have to use another FTP client, if you need to do everything in one go.

There are some command-line clients that can accept file URL.

If you are looking for GUI client, there will be less options.

*My* [WinSCP FTP client](https://winscp.net/) can [accept full file URL on its command-line](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/task_download#url) to initiate a GUI download:

```
winscp ftp://ftp-pub:avilex@ftp.avilex.ru/Pub/schooldesk/schooldesk-20171025.iso
```

[image]

Comment: yes, this does the trick! but for sake of security they make all files hidden for ordinar users. so i finished task with google chrome.